# Flash AS3: Dynamic Photo height being stretched?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flickr

I'm loading in a small thumbnail into a MovieClip as part of my Thumb class... but when I add it to the stage, the height of the thumbnail is stretched dramatically.

I've got my height and width set not only in the Thumb Class, but on the instance of the Thumb that is being added to the stage.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the MovieClip was being sized before there was any content in it. There was no clear indication as to the boundaries, so when the photo finally loaded in, it was trying to occupy a massive area.

Answer (score 0):

Look at all the parent DisplayObjectContainers and make sure none of them have any scaling on the y axis.

Note: That also includes the stage.

Answer (score 0):

Make a test function in your Thumb class or a util class that gets called when the image gets done loaded.

Have the function recurse upward through itself and parents, and print out `width`, `height`, `scaleX`, and `scaleY`.  Stop recursing when you hit the stage.  Your culprit will be the one with the wonky values.

My suspicion is that you are artificially setting `width` and/or `height` on something before the image is loaded, and `scaleX` and `scaleY` are ending up with bad values.  The image then finishes loading, and the scaling is applied.